# use theme for X11

Tags: linux, themes, gtk

HI  all
sorry for my bad English

My program (GTK) runs in Linux (Ubuntu) without any problem and its themes are fine but when I change my system to run just X and then my program, it runs but without any theme. How can I configure my system to use theme in X for my program?

REGARDS

Answer (score 1):

Create a .gtkrc-2.0 in your home folder. Like this:
`touch ~/.gtkrc-2.0`
Then you just have to edit it.
`nano ~/.gtkrc-2.0`
 Using the documentations/howtos.
[Like this](http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/239/gtk-configuration-for-non-gnome-desktop-user/) or [this](http://appdev-notes.blogspot.com/2009/04/gtk-settings-with-gtkrc-20.html) or you can use a tool for all of this (which works more or less). (gtk-chtheme or lxappearance)
If you use your root account to start the X, then obviously you have to copy the gtkrc into the root folder. `sudo cp /home/username/.gtkrc* /root/`

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu configuration tools set the theme using gnome-settings-daemon. This daemon is always running as part of a Gnome session, but if Gnome has not started, it isn't running, and so the theme settings are not applied.

You can either run gnome-settings-daemon in your X session, or manually change your GTK theme settings as suggested by Shiki.